# Change Shell PS1 in tmux using a local version of .bashrc

Tags: command-line, tmux

I'm not sure if this is standard procedure but I load my tmux config locally inside the project so when I press yarn start form a new computer. I can get back to my environment.

**I was wondering if its possible to do the same with .bashrc so that when i load tmux I can pick up my local version of .bashrc from project?**

package.json

```
"scripts" : {
    "start": "chmod u+x ./start.sh && ./start.sh",
    "kill": "tmux kill-session -t dev"
 }
```

start.sh

```
SESSION=dev
tmux new-session -d -s $SESSION
#Just make sure the latest tmux conf is loaded
tmux send-keys 'tmux source-file tmux.conf && clear' C-m
tmux new-window -t $SESSION:1 -n 'WebServer'
tmux send-keys 'node ./start.js' C-m
```

Comment: What do you mean by "load my tmux config locally inside the project so when I press yarn start form a new computer. I can get back to my environment. "?

Comment: I often switch machines so instead of configuring tmux in my profile I've a tmux config file which gets loaded by strat.sh. this way when i clone projects in a local machine it has all the configuration that i want. I wonder if i can do the same thing with bashrc so I can shorten my PS1 and so on...

Comment: FYI: yarn is a package manager like NPM also you can write shortcuts in your project for example when I press yarn start it will execute start.sh